# Vite error with optimized info should be defined when use GLTFLoader in React(ThreeJS)

Tags: reactjs, three.js, vite

I use vite to build one react environment. When I import GLTFLoader from the module, and vite commandline mentioned that:

> Vite Error, /node_modules/.vite/deps/three_examples_jsm_loaders_GLTFLoader.js?v=9d4ee121 optimized info should be defined

Here's my code:

```js
import * as Three from "three"
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader'

[...]

const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader()
gltfLoader.setPath('public/')

gltfLoader.load('000.hdr', gltf => {
    gltf.scene.scale.set(0.2,0.2,0.2)
    scenes.add(gltf.scene)
})
```

Here's the error message:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

For others in the future, YMMV: deleting node_modules and pnpm-lock.yaml solved the issue.

Comment: Also, loaders.gl contributed to the issue for me: https://github.com/visgl/loaders.gl/issues/2176

Comment: In my case, just deleting `node_modules/.vite` folder, then `npm i` solved it

Answer (score 0):

Already solve this question.

When the commandline mentioned vite error, just need to close dev-server, then   reload. Vite would clean the cache tmp files in .vite.

Answer (score 0):

this is usually caused by lockfiles or `node_modules/.cache/vite` (or maybe in your case `node_modules/.vite`)